# JavaScript won't run but works in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following test project in jsFiddle [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4C5a/6/) which runs as expected and JSLint reports code is valid.

I then copy and paste the html into a blank text file in Notepad and save as randomfilename.html

When I click the html file, I see the file chooser and I can select the file but the chart doesn't render. Any ideas why? I've tried in IE, Chrome and Firefox and there's no chart in any of them.

Thank you

EDIT: This is what I now have in a text file named randomfilename.html

It's not working in

`Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m` or the latest firefox/IE for me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
<div id="testString"></div>

<script>

var dataString = new Array (
[1341187200000,592.52],[1341273600000,599.41],[1341446400000,609.94],[1341532800000,605.88],[1341792000000,613.89],[1341878400000,608.21],
[1341964800000,604.43],[1342051200000,598.90],[1342137600000,604.97],[1342396800000,606.91],[1342483200000,606.94],[1342569600000,606.26],
[1342656000000,614.32],[1342742400000,604.30],[1343001600000,603.83]);

function handleFileSelect(evt)
{
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
    {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(reader)
        {
            return function()
            {
                var contents = reader.result;
                document.getElementById('testString').innerHTML=contents;
                var gx;   
                gx=dataString;            
                renderChart(gx);  
}    
        })(reader);

        reader.readAsText(f);
    }
}



function renderChart(data) {
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    };


document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: have you included jQuery after the copypaste?

Comment: Why didn't you put the js in the js area?

Comment: No I haven't. If I'm trying to test this without a server, is there an external address I can use for `src="jquery.js"`? I've only been getting to grips with JS for last 2 days so am a little clueless :)

Comment: @ooo http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Comment: [scriptsrc](http://www.scriptsrc.net) will give you a complete line to paste for jQuery and other plugins: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You should post the code and show us what you inserted in your html file, or what you already have in your file.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck - I've posted the HTML section only of the link in the question.

Comment: The browse button works... What is the chart suppose to look like?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck - can you see the chart in jsFiddle? I've just updated my Q with code. Strangely after posting it Stackoverlow locked and gave me the message "Stack Overflow requires external Javascript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load"

Comment: you HAVE to include jQuery FIRST

Comment: And you really should include <head></head> and put this code inside of <body></body>

Comment: @ianpgall - thanks that's fixed it. I'm just updating it now with proper head/body tags. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're forgetting to include the jQuery library. When using a jsFiddle, it allows you to specify a JS library to be included automatically in your HTML (that you don't physically see). When you copy/paste your HTML from jsFiddle, the jQuery library including is not copied over. Try adding something like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

right above the other `<script>` tags (ONLY in your text file you copy/paste to...you don't need to do this in jsFiddle because it's automatically "done").

Not that this will break it, but you're also missing a `<head>` and `<body>` section in your HTML. I'm not sure if HTML5 makes this optional, but you might want to add those. Even if `<head></head>` is empty, it should be included...and all of your code inside of the current `<html></html>` should be inside of a nested `<body></body>`.

Comment: The code does not appear to need jQuery unless I overlooked it.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn It clearly doesn't. But if you notice the Highcharts library...it requires jQuery. A simple look at their website proves that: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use (look at #1 under step number 1: "Installation")

Comment: nice catch. I have no experience with that lib and would have made the same mistake as OP.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn No problem. I guess I only knew because I've looked into the library before. And it also made me think something needs jQuery because the settings in the jsFiddle are not the default framework "MooTools 1.4.5"